# Multiple subclases with singleton pattern and static methods & variables

Tags: java, design-patterns, static, abstract-class, subclass

firts sorry for my english, i could explain the problem as best i can.

*The **problem***

I have multiple class, that reads more string from a unique XML file.

All of this clases reads from the same file, but the variables are diferent. Because each class reads a different part of the document.

This variables i want to use "static". Because I do not want to instantiate every time I use the class.

I use these classes to return "dynamically" URLs. I use these URLs in Forms, Links, JSP and "request.getRequestDispatcher (#)".

That is why the use of "static" way to not instantiate the class in a JSP/Servlet and can use it directly. (the code is simpler and clean)

Example of class:

```
public class PaginasProductos {

Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

// URL donde se encuentran las paginas
private static String PATH;
// URL para las acciones
private static String RealPath = PaginasGlobales.getPATH();

//Paginas
private static String PaginaListados;
private static String FormularioModificar;
private static String FormularioAlta;


// Acciones = Servlets
private static String AccionAlta;
private static String AccionBaja;
private static String AccionListar;
private static String AccionModificar;
private static String AccionObtener;

// Instancia de la clase
private static PaginasProductos INSTANCIA;

/**
 * Devuelve las URL de las paginas especificas de administracion de productos
 * @return Una instancia con todas las URL de las paginas
 */

public static PaginasProductos getInstance(){
    if (INSTANCIA == null) INSTANCIA = new PaginasProductos();
    return INSTANCIA;
}//Final del metodo, getInstance

private PaginasProductos(){
    String rutaTotal = InicializadorXML.getRutaXmlPaginas();
    SAXBuilder constructor = new SAXBuilder();
    File xml = new File(rutaTotal);
    try{
        Document documento = (Document) constructor.build(xml);

        Element root = documento.getRootElement();

        List<Element> listado = root.getChildren("paginasProductos");

        for (int contador = 0; contador < listado.size(); contador++){
            Element parametro = (Element) listado.get(contador);

            PATH = parametro.getChildText("path");

            PaginaListados = PATH+parametro.getChildText("listado");

            FormularioModificar = PATH+parametro.getChildText("formularioMod");

            FormularioAlta = RealPath+PATH+parametro.getChildText("formularioAlta");

            AccionAlta = RealPath+parametro.getChildText("alta");

            AccionBaja = RealPath+parametro.getChildText("baja");;

            AccionListar = RealPath+parametro.getChildText("listar");

            AccionModificar = RealPath+parametro.getChildText("modificar");

            AccionObtener = RealPath+parametro.getChildText("obtener");
            }
        }catch (IOException e) {
            log.error("Ex (IOException | Constructor | PaginaProductos): " + e.getMessage());
            log.error("¡traza!", e);
        }catch (JDOMException e) {
            log.error("Ex (IOException | Constructor | PaginaProductos): " + e.getMessage());
            log.error("¡traza!", e);
        }catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Ex (Exception | Constructor | PaginaProductos): " + e.getMessage());
            log.error("¡traza!", e);
        }   
} //Fin Constructor PaginasClientes

@SuppressWarnings("javadoc")
public static String getPaginaListados() {
    return PaginaListados;
}

@SuppressWarnings("javadoc")
public static String getFormularioModificar() {
    return FormularioModificar;
}

@SuppressWarnings("javadoc")
public static String getFormularioAlta() {
    return FormularioAlta;
}


@SuppressWarnings("javadoc")
public static String getAccionAlta() {
    return AccionAlta;
}


@SuppressWarnings("javadoc")
public static String getAccionBaja() {
    return AccionBaja;
}


@SuppressWarnings("javadoc")
public static String getAccionListar() {
    return AccionListar;
}


@SuppressWarnings("javadoc")
public static String getAccionModificar() {
    return AccionModificar;
}


@SuppressWarnings("javadoc")
public static String getAccionObtener() {
    return AccionObtener;
}} //Fin Clase PaginasClientes
```

Now what I have done is the same code, replacing "paginasProductos", for each class read their part of the XML.

But I think exists another way to do this. Because I think I can reuse the code and not write again with each class

**Things I've tried**

Generate a Abstract class that contais this code. And the other clases "extends" this.

*Fail*:

As the "father" class has static methods these are not replaced. And the variables always have the same value.

**Posible Solution**
I read about "factory pattern" but not if it solves my problem, which is basically re write the code for each class and make it easier to maintain if I make changes

I tried to think of a way to do it but I can not think of anything better than previously tested

### EDIT

This is the XML file:

http://pastebin.com/aXS0aCxP

- I use Uppercase to variable names becasuse are "static" and i've used it to separate it from the other variables. Normally i use java nomenclature
- The XML file contains the webapp URLs and other information about the Webapp (domain, port..etc). Only this information change (*paginasGlobales*)

***If anyone needs further explanation or to explain something better (my English is not good) I will try to explain again and more clearly***

Comment: Could you post your XML file so I can check my approach below

Comment: Added the XML and Explain something

Comment: Uppercase is for static final variables, not just static.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a `HashMap` to store the products. If you need to add a new product, just add a new value to `productos`. Could you post your XML file?

```
public class PaginasProductos {
     private HashMap<String,String> paginasProductos;
     private String[] productos = {"listado", "formularioMod", ...};

     .....

     public PaginasProductos(){
         String rutaTotal = InicializadorXML.getRutaXmlPaginas();
         SAXBuilder constructor = new SAXBuilder();
         File xml = new File(rutaTotal);
         try{
             Document documento = (Document) constructor.build(xml);
             Element root = documento.getRootElement();
             List<Element> listado = root.getChildren("paginasProductos");
             PATH = parametro.getChildText("path");

             for (int contador = 0; contador < listado.size(); contador++){
                 Element parametro = (Element) listado.get(contador);

                 for(String producto:productos){
                     paginasProductos.put(producto, PATH+parametro.getChildText(producto));
                 }
             }
         }
     }

     public String getProducto(String producto){
         return paginasProductos.get(producto)
     }

}
```

**Edit**

Based on the XML you supplied (snippet below), your code can be simplified.

```
  <paginasProductos>
    <path>administracion/productos/</path>
    <listado>gestionProductos.jsp</listado>
    <formularioMod>formularioModificarProducto.jsp</formularioMod>
    <formularioAlta>formularioAltaProducto.jsp</formularioAlta>
    <alta>AltaProducto</alta>
    <baja>BajaProducto</baja>
    <listar>ListarProductos</listar>
    <modificar>ModificarProducto</modificar>
    <obtener>ObtenerProducto</obtener>
  </paginasProductos>
```

Refactored code does  not need to know about `productos`. Just adding another child element to the `<paginasProductos>` tag will result in a new `producto`.

```
public class PaginasProductos {
     private HashMap<String,String> paginasProductos;

     .....

     public PaginasProductos(){
         String rutaTotal = InicializadorXML.getRutaXmlPaginas();
         SAXBuilder constructor = new SAXBuilder();
         File xml = new File(rutaTotal);
         try{
             Document documento = (Document) constructor.build(xml);
             Element root = documento.getRootElement();
             List<Element> listado = root.getChildren("paginasProductos");
             PATH = parametro.getChildText("path");

             for (int contador = 0; contador < listado.size(); contador++){
                 Element parametro = (Element) listado.get(contador);
                 paginasProductos.put(parametro.getTagName(), PATH+parametro.getChildText(producto));
             }
         }
     }

     public String getProducto(String producto){
         return paginasProductos.get(producto)
     }

}
```

**EDIT**

Based on your comment you can further refactor:

```
public class Paginas {
     private HashMap<String,String> paginas;

     .....

     // sectionName = "paginasProductos", etc.
     public Paginas(String sectionName ){
         String rutaTotal = InicializadorXML.getRutaXmlPaginas();
         SAXBuilder constructor = new SAXBuilder();
         File xml = new File(rutaTotal);
         try{
             Document documento = (Document) constructor.build(xml);
             Element root = documento.getRootElement();
             List<Element> listado = root.getChildren(sectionName );
             PATH = parametro.getChildText("path");

             for (int contador = 0; contador < listado.size(); contador++){
                 Element parametro = (Element) listado.get(contador);
                 paginas.put(parametro.getTagName(), PATH+parametro.getChildText(producto));
             }
         }
     }

     public String getPaginas(String page){
         return paginas.get(page);
     }

}
```

Now you create an instance of `Paginas` for each group in your XML file. Perhaps you could have a PaginasManager to keep them all together.

```
public class PaginasManager{
    private HashMap<String,String> paginasSections;

    ....

    public PaginasManager(String[] sectionNames){
        for(String sectionName:sectionNames){
            paginasSections.put(sectionName, new Paginas(sectionName));
        }
    }

    public String getPaginas(String section, String page){
        return paginasSections.get(section).get(page);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, but in this case, i have nothing "static" so I have to instantiate the "PaginasProductos" class to use it. I understand I can do everything "static" like I had in my code.

Also I have to "copy and paste" in all other classes without being able to reuse code.

This solution gives less code (thank you very much for your time, I'll use) but does not solve the other problem. Is there any way to solve the other problems?

Comment: There is no particular reason to have static anything in this case, you may wish to enforce a singleton, but that is different. By all other classes, I presume, based on your XML, that you mean to have PaginasGlobales, PaginasClientes, etc. - is that correct?

Comment: Yes is correct, i like to use this classes around the time os the aplication. I have a class for each CRUD.

Answer (score 1):

Since your current approach consits of a bunch of anti-patterns I'll start with some general considerations. This ain't solve your problem but maybe guide you the way. Some basic information is missing but based on the code I'll make the following assumptions:

- You're developing a WebApplication (*.war)
- You want to cache information stored in a XML-File for an unknown period of time.
- You want to seperate the code to load specifics parts of the xml

Here are my suggestions:

- Using static declarations in WebApp's should be avoided, at least if you don't want to cope with all the "thread-safe" considerations. If you want to have a single instance of whatever have a look at the **Scopes** of an WebApplication, especially the **ApplicationScope** in your case. This way you should get rid of the static problem.
- How to structure your code to load the XML-File just once and applying different "Reader-Logic" the **CommandPattern** will tell you. You mentioned subclassing, this will be part of it.
- The peace of code which will read the XML-File doesn't need to be static. Just check if the data has already been loaded, like you did for the instance check in the singleton-pattern you already applied.
- In Java, please, don't use uppercase variable names. Always start with lowercase letters.

In order to get a more specific answer some need to know about the *lifecycle* of the XML-Content. Is it static or will it change while the server is running? In the latter case you might apply a Time-Based Cache Implementation. A bunch of them are out there for Java.

Bye the way, absolutely no problem to understand your english, hope the same applies to mine;-)

Comment: The XML document is not modified more than at the beginning of the application, to save the port and other information. I've posted the document. I'll see "aplicationScope" and other. ---> EDIT Afteer see this --> I think what you want to do is use this: -- application.setAttribute("paginasProductos", new PaginasProductos()); -- In this case i can use "no static" class (and class inheritance), and only instanciate one time, right?